# Regex to match string with more than one keyword in a list

Tags: regex

Can I have a regex matching strings that:

- containing more than 1 keyword in a list, and
- the order of keywords in the string can be arbitrary

Given a keyword list (not limited to 3 items but can be reasonably short (e.g. <10 items)):

```
apple
banana
cherry
```

Want to match:

```
loved apple and banana.
cherry is purple and banana is yellow.
apple, banana, cherry are all fruits.
```

But not matching:

```
apple tastes good.
a yellow fruit can be an banana.
```

Optional not match (if possible):

```
cherry is cherry
```

- It's like to count number of keywords in a string and select those with more than one keywords.
- I want this because I cannot have control flow written in some random app (only possible way to define a filter in that app is to write a regex).
- I don't know what regex library that app use (assume it's using a modern one).

further question:
can i have a regex that match strings containing at least `k` keywords in an `N`-item keyword list?

Comment: Are you willing to get language-specific in this question or do you want this to be a pure regex approach?  If you would accept answers that aid with non-regex features, you may be able to get a better answer for your needs.  For instance, my answer can be much cleaner and more flexible if you were using Javascript, C#, and so on, as then there are more options available to work with the issue.

Comment: @pwilcox I would like to write some script, which is simple and straight, but the app i'm using just don't support any scripting, leaving regex as only solution. So, mind-blowing regexs' are welcomed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^.*?(apple|banana|cherry).*?((?!\1)(?:apple|banana|cherry)).*?$
```

##### Short Explanation

- `^` Start of a string
- `.*?` Non-greedy match of any character
- `(apple|banana|cherry)` Capture one of the names as the first captured group
- `(` Capturing group

  - `(?!\1)` Match next group negating the exact value of the first captured group
  - `(?:apple|banana|cherry)` One of the names
- `)` Close group

See the regex [demo1](https://regex101.com/r/j1pUTX/1)

##### *Edit:* Use shorten version

```
^.*?(apple|banana|cherry).*?((?!\1)(?1)).*?$
```

See the regex [demo2](https://regex101.com/r/hh2XX1/1)

**NOTE:** I've used second captured group at `((?!\1)(?:apple|banana|cherry))` just for highlighting keywords. You can use `(?:(?!\1)(?:apple|banana|cherry))` instead.

Comment: Surprisingly simple and straightforward (reuse the capturing group `^.*?(apple|banana|cherry).*?((?!\1)(?1)).*?$` for easy maintenance of keyword list (PCRE) `:)` )